# Does yolov5 pytorch use a different labeling format?

Tags: object-detection, yolov5

I am doing object detection in yolo v5 in an  dataset annotated for older version .But in tutorials I found that we have to choose yolov5 pytorch format .Is there any difference ,will the older annotated data work??

Comment: It follows the same format as the earlier versions of Yolo

Answer (score 4):

Yes, It works. I have recently used it and labelled according to following label [format](https://github.com/AlexeyAB/Yolo_mark/issues/60):

`.txt`-file for each `.jpg` -image-file - in the same directory and with the same name, but with .txt-extension, and put to file: object number and object coordinates on this image, for each object in new line:
`<object-class> <x> <y> <width> <height>`

Where:

- integer number of object from `0` to `(classes-1)`
    - float values relative to width and height of image, it can be equal from `(0.0 to 1.0]`
for example: `<x> = <absolute_x> / <image_width>` or `<height> = <absolute_height> / <image_height>`
atention: `<x> <y>` - are center of rectangle (are not top-left corner)

Answer (score 0):

For training **YOLOv5** on custom datasets (or make sure you have these):

- First you have to create a **dataset.yaml**
- Next you have to label your images, export your labels to **YOLO format**, with one *.txt file per image (if no objects in image, no *.txt file is required).
- Then you need to organise your **train** and **val** images and labels accordingly.

You can find a detailed description about it here:
[yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/wiki/Train-Custom-Data)