# Convert unknown labels to Yolov5

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, yolov5

I own a dataset of images with unknown label format, which is:

```
angry_actor_104.jpg 0 28 113 226 141 22.9362 0
```

It indicates an image as follows:

**image_name face_id_in_image face_box_top face_box_left face_box_right face_box_bottom face_box_cofidence expression_label**

My question is: How can this be converted into the yolov5 format?

I have been looking this up for a long time and hope someone can help.
Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since the format is unknown you are unlikely to find existing code to completely handle the transformation but I can share some tips to get started.

1. The annotations file does not have enough info to get converted to Yolo format. Because to convert to Yolo you also need to know the dimensions of the  images. If all of your images are the same dimension then it easier but if all of the images are different then you will need additional code to extract the dimensions of the images. I will explain why below.
2. When you are done you will need to get the images and labels in a specific directly structure like this, with one txt file per image:

   ```
   /images/actor1.jpg
   /images/actor2.jpg
   /labels/actor1.txt
   /labels/actor2.txt
   ```
3. This is the shape that you want to get the annotation files into.

   ```
   face_id_in_image x_center_image y_center_image width height
   ```

   There is a clear description of what the values mean here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563144/5183735.

   Now you need to do some math to calculate the values.

   - width = (face_box_right - face_box_left)/image_width
   - height = (face_box_bottom - face_box_top)/image_height
   - x_center_image = face_box_left/image_width + (width/2)
   - y_center_image = face_box_top/image_height + (height/2)

I have some bits of code that may help you with reading the text file and saving the text files here.
https://github.com/pylabel-project/pylabel/blob/main/pylabel/exporter.py and https://github.com/pylabel-project/pylabel/blob/main/pylabel/importer.py.

If you are able to share your exact files I may be able to identify some shortcut to transform them.