# YOLOv5 Dataset Format Issues

Tags: dataset, yolov5

I have dataset in the form bbox "2947 1442 40 40" I want to convert it into YoloV5 format. I don't know exactly how can I can convert this notation to YOLOv5.

Answer (score 1):

**Example**:

- Image properties: width=1156 pix, height=1144 pix.
- bounding box properties: xmin=1032, ymin=20, xmax=1122, ymax=54, object_name="Ring".
- Let objects_list="bracelet","Earring","Ring","Necklace"

**YOLOv5 format:** f"{category_idx} {x1 + bbox_width / 2} {y1 + bbox_height / 2} {bbox_width} {bbox_height}\n"

- $bbox_{width} = x_{max}/width - x_{min}/width = (1122-1032)/1156 = 0.07785467128027679$
- $bbox_{height} = y_{max}/height - y_{min}/height = (54-20)/1144 = 0.029720279720279717$
- $x_{center}=x_{min}/width+bbox_{width}/2 = 0.9316608996539792$
- $y_{center}=y_{min}/height + bbox_{height}/2 = 0.032342657342657344$
- category_idx=2
- Final result: **2 0.9316608996539792 0.032342657342657344 0.07785467128027679 0.029720279720279717**

Answer (score 0):

You don't have quite enough information to convert that annotation to Yolo.

The yolo format looks like this

```
0 0.588196 0.474138 0.823607 0.441645
<class-label x_center_image y_center_image width height>
```

There is a clear description of what the values mean here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563144/5183735.

So in order to convert your annotations you will also need to know the class-label and the height and width of your image.

If you have those things let me know and I may be able to provide more help. Also do you know what tool created those annotations? There be other documentation on how to convert annotations of that type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import images with labels in Roboflow, then export them in Yolov5 PyTorch format.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).