# How YOLO do with 2 object centers at same grid

Tags: object-detection, yolo

I am trying to better understand YOLO.
When converting the ground truth bounding boxes into targets for model, as I understand:

```
grid[x // grid_size, y // grid_size, 0 : anchors_number] = [x % grid_size, y % grid_size, obj_width, obj_height, conf...]
```

Am I wrong? If not, how YOLO work with 2 objects with the same center grid.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Yolo can deal with 2 objects in the same image. You just need to create 2 rows in your annotation file.

This is a sample annotation file with 2 boxes of the same class, class 0:

```
0 0.588196 0.474138 0.823607 0.441645
0 0.688196 0.574138 0.723607 0.341645
```

The schema for the annotations is:

```
<class-label x_center_image y_center_image width height>
```

There is a clear description of what the values mean here https://stackoverflow.com/a/66563144/5183735.

Comment: Your answer is not for my question. Thank you.